# Elements rotating around centre of DIV - only last one added to page responds to onClick event

Tags: javascript, css

I have six divs inside a main one. They rotate around its centre as intended.

They should all have a different image and bring up some related text when clicked.

When clicked, all elements respond to the onClick events of the rotating div with the highest Z index. If more have equal Z index, then the last one added.

From what I gathered using FireBug, each rotating div is contained inside a bigger square that rotates with it, which creates a layer that covers all the other ones.

Is there a way to work around this problem?

This is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/desktop.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Rotating images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-round">

            <div class="div0" id = "0" style = "z-index : 15" onClick = "alert ( this.id + ' - ' + this.style.zIndex )"></div>
            <div class="div1" id = "1" style = "z-index : 15" onClick = "alert ( this.id + ' - ' + this.style.zIndex )"></div> 
            <div class="div2" id = "2" style = "z-index : 10" onClick = "alert ( this.id + ' - ' + this.style.zIndex )"></div>
            <div class="div3" id = "3" style = "z-index : 10" onClick = "alert ( this.id + ' - ' + this.style.zIndex )"></div>              
            <div class="div4" id = "4" style = "z-index : 10" onClick = "alert ( this.id + ' - ' + this.style.zIndex )"></div>
            <div class="div5" id = "5" style = "z-index : 10" onClick = "alert ( this.id + ' - ' + this.style.zIndex )"></div>      
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS

```
div {
    float : left;
}

.container-round {
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 350px;
}

.div0 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 18%;
    height: 25%;
    background: url(../images/img0.jpg) no-repeat 500px center;
    animation: orbit0 10s linear infinite;
}

.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/img1.jpg) no-repeat 500px center;
    animation: orbit1 10s linear infinite;
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/img2.jpg) no-repeat 500px center;
    animation: orbit2 10s linear infinite;
}

.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/img3.jpg) no-repeat 500px center;
    animation: orbit3 10s linear infinite;
}

.div4 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/img4.jpg) no-repeat 500px center;
    animation: orbit4 10s linear infinite;
}

.div5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/img5.jpg) no-repeat 500px center;
    animation: orbit5 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit0 { 
from { transform:rotate(0deg); } to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes orbit1 { 
    from { transform:rotate(60deg); } to { transform: rotate(420deg); }
}

@keyframes orbit2 { 
    from { transform:rotate(120deg); } to { transform: rotate(480deg); }
}

@keyframes orbit3 { 
    from { transform:rotate(180deg); } to { transform: rotate(540deg); }
}

@keyframes orbit4 { 
    from { transform:rotate(240deg); } to { transform: rotate(600deg); }
}

@keyframes orbit5 { 
    from { transform:rotate(300deg); } to { transform: rotate(660deg); }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem, the same image is expected. The client will provide them later, and I am using a random one. What I cannot understand is why when i click on any image it's always the same ID in the alert that comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help -

**CSS and HTML**

```css
.container{
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  animation: orbit0 10s linear infinite;
}

.img{
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 27.78%;
  height: 16.67%;
}

.first {
    top: 8.33%;
    left: 36.11%;
    background-image: url(http://68.169.58.245/darryl/images/img1.jpg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.second {
    top: 25%;
    left: 65.27%;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    background-image: url(http://68.169.58.245/darryl/images/img1.jpg);
}

.third {
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 65.27%;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    background-image: url(http://68.169.58.245/darryl/images/img1.jpg);
}

.forth {
    bottom: 8.33%;
    left: 36.11%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    background-image: url(http://68.169.58.245/darryl/images/img1.jpg);
}

.fifth {
    transform: rotate(240deg);
    bottom: 25%;
    right: 65.27%;
    background-image: url(http://68.169.58.245/darryl/images/img1.jpg);
}

.sixth {
    top: 25%;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
    right: 65.27%;
    background-image: url(http://68.169.58.245/darryl/images/img1.jpg);
}

@keyframes orbit0 { 
from { transform:rotate(0deg); } to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img first" id="1" onclick="alert(this.id+'-'+this.className)">
  </div>
  <div class="img second" id="2" onclick="alert(this.id+'-'+this.className)">
  </div>
  <div class="img third" id="3" onclick="alert(this.id+'-'+this.className)">
  </div>
  <div class="img forth" id="4" onclick="alert(this.id+'-'+this.className)">
  </div>
  <div class="img fifth" id="5" onclick="alert(this.id+'-'+this.className)">
  </div>
  <div class="img sixth" id="6" onclick="alert(this.id+'-'+this.className)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rajesh, thank you very much for your help, it did the trick! Also, apologies for my unexpected prolonged absence, I always try to be as quick as possible, sometimes things happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

From your `css`, each div 1 through 5 is using the same image: `background: url(../images/img1.jpg)`. That would explain why all divs are displaying the same image.

For the on-click: The reason you're seeing the same thing is that all your divs 1-5 are taking up 100% of the width and height. You're just offsetting where the image itself is displayed. So, when you click anywhere, you're actually clicking on the top-most element. To get around that, you probably want to move away from `width:100%`, `height:100%` and instead position the image alone. That is, set the div to the image size then apply the appropriate transform to get it to the location you want.
Might be a good idea to also add a `border: 1px solid red;` to the divs while you're debugging just to see where your divs actually are.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, hadn't even thought that might be an issue but I will give it a go :-)

Comment: @adilpapaya, I did try that with one of those elements and i edited the code above accordingly. Now that div is not showing the background image and is just spinning on itself, at the top right of the containing DIV ( http://68.169.58.245/darryl/ ). That happens if I use % for width and height ( 18 x 25 ), or correct number of pixels ( 132 x 175 ). Your suggestion that the problem was in the 100% measurements was correct, but to change that i will have to find a different way to render the animation...

Comment: Dan, I think @Rajesh below has you covered :)